.NetCore EF - Main query used by sync/async query
So I have a main sync query like:
private List<MyCustomClass> Foo()
{
    return _ctx.Table1.Where(...).Select(s => new MyCustomClass { ... }).ToList();
}

and I need to use the results of it in a sync query:
1. return Foo().Where(...).GroupBy(...).Select(s => new MyCustomClass2 { ... }).ToList();

AND ALSO in an async query:
2. return await Foo().Where(...).GroupBy(...).Select(s => new MyCustomClass3 { ... }).ToListAsync();

cause I need to filter the main query results for other fields and then group by and get other informations.
The (1) query does work but the (2) query does not (it doesn't even show .ToListAsync()).
I would like to leave both doors open.
I already try to add AsQueryable() to the main query but it doesn't work.
Someone could help me?
Thanks a lot.

If you want to chain queries, return IQueryable from functions and remove ToList(). materialization should be at the end.

In a nutshell, using IQueryable enables both asynchronous and synchronous consumption:
private IQueryable<Table1> Foo()
{
    IQueryable<Table1> query =_ctx.Table1.Where(...);
    return query;
}

Then when you go to call "Foo()":
// synchronous code:
var results = Foo()
    .Select(s => new MyCustomClass { ... });
    .ToList();

// asynchronous code:
var results = await Foo()
    .GroupBy(...)
    .Select(s => new MyCustomClass3 { ... })
    .ToListAsync();

If you want Foo() to have basic global conditions, but then a call consuming those results wants to expand on the Where condition, that is fine:
var results = await Foo()
    .Where(... more conditions, will be ANDed to existing conditions ...)
    .GroupBy(...)
    .Select(s => new MyCustomClass3 { ... })
    .ToListAsync();

This provides maximum flexibility while enabling deferred execution for the IQueryable. You can use whatever projection you want, eager load related entities if that is what you want, get a Count or exists check with .Any() etc. Very powerful and results in efficient queries when used properly.

Thank u so much, I try but for the async subquery I have the error: the query blabla can't be translated.. I need to add a AsEnumerable() or ToList() and so on.. but I don't understand where I have to add AsEnumerable() or ToList() to make it work.

"the query blabla can't be translated" you need to mention the exact error

Ok, I solved my error in query, now work fine! Thanks a lot Steve Py
